# When is the preimage of codomain not equal to domain?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need to show that 
For every $X\subseteq A$, $X \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$, where $f: A\to B$. 
I think I understand why this is true. However, under what circumstances are they not equal? When is $f^{-1}(f(X)) \not= X$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733463/understanding-the-inclusion-c-subseteq-f-1fc

Comment: Oh, did not find that in my search. That does clear it up for me though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different when the function is not injective. For example:
$$
A=\{0;1\},\quad f:A\rightarrow A,\quad f(0)=f(1)=0,\quad  f^{-1}(f(\{0\}))=f^{-1}(\{0\})=\{0;1\}\neq\{0\}.
$$