# Why is that any function from $X$ to the trivial topological space is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functions

I think this is a super silly question, but I just can't figure out why is that given *any* function $f: X \to Y$, where $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is an arbitrary topological space, and $(Y, \mathcal{T}_{trivial})$ where $ \mathcal{T}_{trivial} = \{\varnothing, Y\}$

Okay, so $f^{-1}(\varnothing) = \varnothing \in \mathcal{T}$, but how do we know that $f^{-1}(Y) \in \mathcal{T}?$ Since the preimage of the codomain is not necessarily the domain 
[When is the preimage of codomain not equal to domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787846/when-is-the-preimage-of-codomain-not-equal-to-domain)

Why couldn't there be a case where $f^{-1}(Y) = U \subset X$, but $U \notin \mathcal{T}?$

---

Edit: So is it always the case that $f^{-1}(Y) = X$, given $f: X \to Y$?

Comment: the preimage of the codomain is the domain; everything in $X$ gets maps to $Y$.

Comment: All the points of the domain are mapped to the codomain so the preimage of the codomain contains the domain.

Comment: Buf of course $f^{-1}(Y) = X$, for every function $f\colon X\to Y$. For every $x\in X$, $f(x)\in Y$, so $x \in f^{-1}(Y)$. Your title is a little confusing. There are many "trivial" (indiscrete) spaces. I thought by "the" trivial space that perhaps you meant a/the one-point space.

Comment: @BrianO Sorry, calling it the indiscrete topology from now on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, for $f\colon X\to Y$ and $B\subseteq Y$,
$$
f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X:f(x)\in B\}
$$
In particular, for $B=Y$,
$$
f^{-1}(Y)=\{x\in X:f(x)\in Y\}
$$
and therefore $f^{-1}(Y)=X$.

The question you link has a very misleading title.

Comment: @Lookbehindyou No need to be sorry! 